# I want to Access enTranslations provided in one JS File as shown Below, But I am not Able to access it

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, web

As You can see in my HTML I want to take my Data according to my current locale, and I have custom translation file enTranslation, which is given.

PROBLEM :

> I am not able to see the values on browser page,
>             when I am using `{{ translations[key] }}` OR `{{ translation.key }}`

Please HELP me understand what is needed to be done to make this work.

I have 3 files in js Directory, Given Code Below:

1. enTranslations.js
2. prax_controller.js
3. angular_1.4.2.min.js

My HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/angular_1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/prax_controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/enTranslations.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Prax Local</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="prxApp" ng-controller="prxController">
    <div>
    List
        <ul class="d1" ng-repeat="(key, value) in eventHistories">
            <li class="d1k">
                <!--  {{ translations.key }}: {{ value }}% -->
                {{ translations[key] }}  :  {{ value }}%
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### 1. enTranslations.js

```
var translations = {
    "Device Status":'Device Status',
    "Device Temperature":'Device Temperature',
};
```

### 2. prax_controller.js

```
var prxApp = angular.module('prxApp', []);
prxApp.controller('prxController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.init = function() 
{
    $scope.eventHistories = {
            "Device Status":0,
            "Device Temperature":0,
        };
};

$scope.init();
}]);
```

### 3. Angular.min.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js

Comment: can you create a plunker of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can attach the translations on the `$rootScope` then you will be able to get the object in any template. A rough picture that comes in mind according to your requirement could be this.

put this somewhere in your main angular bootstrapping module's run method or you can put it in resolve method of your first controller.

```
angular.module('app').config(function () {
})
.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $http) {
    // Get language based on browser settings
    var lang  = navigator.language;

    // fetch translations from server
    $http.get('URL_TO_FETCH_TRANSLATION/' + lang)
    .success(function (data) {
        $rootScope.translations = data;
    });
});
```

In any of your template.

```
<li class="d1k" ng-repeat="(key, value) in eventHistories">
        {{ translations[key] }}  :  {{ value }}
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Angular controller doesn't know anything about your enTranslations.js file. A slightly less important problem is that you should put the `ng-repeat` on the the `li` instead of the `ul`.

[Here's a codepen that works](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/waRzaX?editors=101)

If you want something to be accessed with handlebars `{{ translations }}`, then it needs to have a corresponding `$scope.translations` object in your controller.

Simply creating that object in your controller will fix your problem.

```
$scope.translations = {
  "Device Status": 'Device Status',
  ...
}
```

Now its understandable that you don't want to have to put this in every controller. You can create a JSON object, keep that on the server somewhere and access it using Angular's `$http` service, or you can create some globals via `$rootScope` or via [constants](http://twofuckingdevelopers.com/2014/06/angularjs-best-practices-001-constants/) in your app config.

Comment: Hi Azium, thanks for answer,
I am loading translation object based on locale, enTranslation, keTranslations are different language files which contains translation object, which will be loaded based on locale.
how can I attach them in $scope.translations={.....}?